# What does a type name beginning with '<' mean?

Tags: c#, reflection

In C#, when reflecting types of objects, what does a class name beginning with '<' denote?

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: post an example of code where such name exist

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a type generated by the compiler (for instance when you create a closure, an iterator block, an async method or an anonymous type). You can't refer to it by name in your code.

Comment: +1 - `<` is not a valid character in a C# class name but is in IL

Comment: +1 and that type will be decorated with `CompilerGenerated` attribute